# I need to free up memory in an app am building

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, process, task

am using noHistory in the android manifest but my memory keeps building up and eventually is making my app crash, basically what am doing is having buttons allowing user to navigate left and right and after the 20th or so activity phone crashes because memory start running low on ram,

```
noHistory
```

is not working can someone help?
thank you

I saw somenthing that might work but can someone explain it how to use the

```
recycle()
```

and how it works thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keeping no history will not guarantee memory to be automatically reclaimed...

in fact, it is not guaranteed that your activity will be garbage collected when its onDestroy is called

this is a broad topic

take a look at to begin with

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

and this great video

http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html

Comment: i read it but i still dont understand it :(, am watching the video now

Comment: thank you that video really helped a lot, turns out that if i call recycle with finish together i patch the aplication i dont know if its the best way but the memory leaking that i was having stops and the aplication doesnt crash because of that anymore :) i really apreciate your help